# Linking ghost blog in my webapp subfolder

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I have create a web app and ghost blog. Web app is running on port 80 and ghost blog on 2368 (default for ghost).

I want to add blog page in **mydomain/blog**. 
Can anyone help me out with this.

I am able to run the blog on port 80 using **nginx** but how to run it on particular route of our web app.

this is config file of nginx

```
server {
    listen 3333;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }
    location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;    
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

My app which is hosted on port 1337 is working fine on **3333 nginx link**
but when i am opening **localhost:3333/blog** then blog is not coming properly. it text is coming but its totally distorted seems link css is missing.

So I have two issues regarding this

**1. How to host blog properly on mydomain/blog which is localhost:3333/blog in this case.**

**2. When i am trying to open any page (in spite of its looking distorted) then since that particular route is not found in our main app hence it redirects them to home page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally able to run it so i am going to answer it here

Lets suppose i have a app and a blog. I have run the app on **example.com** and blog on **example.com/blog**

**1. App related setting**

Lets say you app is running on port 1337.

**2. Install ghost properly**

a. you can use [this link](https://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/)  to install ghost.

b. change url of config file of ghost to **http://example.com/blog**

c. restart the ghost.

```
npm start --production
```

or

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

**3 Install nginx properly**

a. you can use [this link](https://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-proxy-port-80-to-2368-for-ghost-with-nginx/) to install nginx.

b. now create **example.conf** file in /etc/nginx/site-enabled folder.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }
    location ^~ /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

c. restart the nginx service.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Hi, when you say X-Real-IP do we leave it like that or what Ip do we put there? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is hosting Ghost in a subdirectory. This link describes what steps you need to take to make that work: https://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/.

Let me know if it worked :).

Comment: could you please check 2 things:
1) update the URL property in `config.js` to contain your subdirectory
2) remove the rewrite from your blog location (that's what breaks your CSS) and make sure to include all headers

`location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }`

Comment: 404 is coming on removing rewrites and using above code.
But with following line
rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;

page is coming but assets (js,css) are not coming as 
page is trying to find assets on 
mydomain/assets path inspite of mydomain/blog/assets where they are acually present.

Can you help me out with ?

Comment: As I wrote above: you need to update the URL property in `config.js` which is part of Ghost to make the blog available in the subdirectory. After that, your blog will only respond from the subdirectory.

Second step: After you blog is configured correctly you don't need the redirect anymore.